# EJB3 injection is Null in Wicket AuthenticateWebSession

Tags: java, session, ejb, wicket

I'm using Wicket + EJB3 in an application and I face a problem but I can't find any topic related, so here it is:

I'm using Wicket authentication, and need to use methods from an EJB in the overrided methods authenticate(...).

I can use this EJB in any wicket page, but when it comes to the WebSession, it stays Null, the injection is not working somehow.

My WicketSession class looks something like this:

```
public class WicketSession extends AuthenticatedWebSession {

   @EJB(name = "UserService")
   private UserService userService;

   private User user = null;

   public WicketSession(Request request) {
    super(request);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean authenticate(final String login, final String password) {

      user = userService.findByLoginPwd(login, password);

      return user != null;;
   }

   public User getUser() {
      return user;
   }

   public void setUser(User user) {
      this.user = user;
   }
}
```

And my EJB3:

```
@Remote
public interface UserService {
    public User findByLoginPwd(final String login, final String pwd);
}

@Stateless
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

   public User findByLoginPwd(final String login, final String pwd) {
       [...]
   }
}
```

The Web part with Wicket is packaged in a war, the business part with EJBs is packaged in a jar, and then I make a ear to deploy it on a JOnAS server.

Any help would be highly appreciated =)

Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sean Patrick Floyd noted, Sessions are not components, so the automatic injection supplied for Wicket components doesn't apply.

A common idiom for injecting stuff in a non-component is to add the line

```
    InjectorHolder.getInjector().inject(this);
```

to the constructor.

I haven't used this for a `WicketSession` extension, but I don't know of a reason it won't work.

In `JavaEEComponentInjector`, the inject method is almost certainly doing a JNDI lookup, and you could do a JNDI lookup yourself to get the object, but this is reusing the existing injection, and if you decide to change injectors (say by extending `JavaEEComponentInjector`), it ensures that you'll continue to use the same injection.

Comment: *less risky than trying to just replicate what happens in the injector* This is pretty much exactly what happens in the ComponentInjector :-)  (+1)

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: See my update.  Hope that's a better explanation.  And thanks for the +1.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's exactly what I was looking for =D It's working like a charm now !

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the injection works with an [`IComponentInstantiationListener`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/application/IComponentInitializationListener.html) (at least that's how the Spring version works). **Update:** it does, see [this document](http://wicketstuff.org/confluence/display/STUFFWIKI/How+to+use+EJB+annotation).

However, `Sessions` are not components, so a different mechanism is needed. Perhaps there is a way to wire your `Session` in the [`Application.newSession()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Application.html#newSession%28org.apache.wicket.Request%2C%20org.apache.wicket.Response%29) method? You will have to take a look at the implementation of `JavaEEComponentInjector` and copy what it does when creating your session.

Comment: Thanks for the answer =) I'll take a look at this. I do have this in the init() methode of my WicketApplication class:  addComponentInstantiationListener(new JavaEEComponentInjector(this));

Comment: I can't, I'm totally new to the website and I need 15 reputation to vote up, sorry =/

Comment: @Nicolas no prob, just wanted to make you aware of voting :-)

Comment: Allright, I checked the JavaEEComponentInjector source code, and all it does is using a mysterious `bind(webapp)` method which I can't find anywhere ... so much for re-using it =(

Comment: @Nicolas don't just look at the source code statically, use your IDE to follow the code

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: Thanks a lot to you too, even though I wasn't able to solve my problem this way, it was obviously a solution as good as the other =)

Comment: @Nicolas you're welcome and as I wrote under Don's answer: that's what the JavaEE injector does internally if you look at these links:  http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/wicketstuff/javaee-inject/1.4.14/javaee-inject-1.4.14-sources.jar!/org/wicketstuff/javaee/injection/JavaEEComponentInjector.java?format=ok http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/wicket/wicket-ioc/1.4.15/wicket-ioc-1.4.15-sources.jar!/org/apache/wicket/injection/ComponentInjector.java?format=ok

Comment: @Sean Patrcik Floyd: Yep, exactly the same, I definitely looked at the wrong files ... my bad